# ¿Por qué si borro "@window.event" la función deja de funcionar?

Tags: python

Este aplicacion muestra un contador y con las teclas de dirección se puede mover e incrementar su valor.

Mi duda es que si borro el `@window.event` no puedo mover ni decrementar el contador.

¿Por qué es nesesario ponerlo?

```
import pyglet 
from pyglet.window import key


window = pyglet.window.Window(width=134,height=132)#se crea la ventana
mos = 17



@window.event #funcion on_key_press se ejecuta mientra la funcion windows se ejecuta
def on_key_press(key_pressed, mod):
    if key_pressed == key.RIGHT:
        label.x+=5  
    if key_pressed == key.LEFT:
        label.x-=5        
    if key_pressed == key.UP:

        global mos
        mos+=1
        label.text=(str(mos))

label = pyglet.text.Label(str(mos),
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=mos,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window.event#funcion on_key_press se ejecuta mientra la funcion windows se ejecuta
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
```

Answer (score 2):

A estos elementos de la sintaxis de python se los conocen como ["decoradores"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator). Básicamente, un *decorador* crea una función a partir de otra función, diciénsose que la ha "decorado" (también funcionaría para "decorar" clases).

En tu caso, `@window.event` es un decorador de `window` que toma la función que le sigue como un gestor de eventos de la ventana.